# How do I open the Intel HD Graphics menu? (Ctrl Alt f12 hotkey is disabled)

Tags: windows-7, intel-graphics

`ctrl + alt + f12` used to open up Intel HD Graphics 3000 settings. I open it yesterday (with that hotkey (I don't know any other way)) and made some gamma adjustments that I need to revert; I also disabled hotkeys since `ctrl + alt + arrow` made my screen change orientation all the time ;P Now I can't find my way back to that menu. (since the hotkey is disabled)

- **OS**: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- **Processor**: i5 2430m
- **Display adapters**: Intel HD Graphics 3000 & AMD Radeon 6650M
- Acer Aspire 7750g Laptop

I've tried typing `Intel` in the start menu, but all I get up is SSD Toolbox, Turbo boost monitor and rapid storage technology. Oh intel... why do you hide from me?

Does anyone know how to open the Intel HD Graphics menu?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On desktop right click and click on graphics properties.....